# How to make font text responsive on resize?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is responsive but text content is not responsive it is not decreasing as the width change.

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">Hello I want to resize.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle
    {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:250px;
    font-size:200%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkEMR/6056/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use viewport value instead of ems, pxs or pts.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Try `font-size:7vw;`.

```
.circle
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:250px;
font-size:7vw; //changed this
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
background:#000
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rkEMR/6058/)**